# Typescript Interface: Why does Typescript allow incompatible interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, i am bit confuse about Typescript interface. It's best to show in the actual code

```
interface Schedule {
    scheduleId: number
    projectId: number
    scheduleVersions: ScheduleVersions[]
}

interface ScheduleVersions {
    created: string
}

function format(b: Schedule) {
  let id = b.projectId 
  let scheduleId = b.scheduleId
    return b.scheduleVersions[0].created + String(id) + String(scheduleId)
}

interface IPromise <T> {
    then <U> ( f: (a:T) => U ) : IPromise<U>
}

//missing properties 
var c : IPromise<{ scheduleId: number }>
// here it should error, isn't it? because format function expect Schedule in it argument
// and type inside IPromise have 2 missing properties.
c.then(format)
```

that's it, why does Typescript doesn't give me an error? telling me that type inside IPromise isn't compatible with Schedule.